# Analytic number theory-Are these sums equal?

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, natural-numbers

I am studying analytic number theory by myself and I came across with two posts that seem to confuse me . [Let $S(x)=\sum_{p\le x,\; q\le x,\; pq\gt x}\frac{1}{pq}$, where p and q are primes. Find the limit of this function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323336/let-sx-sum-p-le-x-q-le-x-pq-gt-x-frac1pq-where-p-and-q-are-pri?rq=1)

[Show that $\sum_{pq\leq x}\frac{1}{pq}$ = $(\ln \ln x)^2+O(\ln \ln x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138316/show-that-sum-pq-leq-x-frac1pq-ln-ln-x2o-ln-ln-x#comment6465763_3138316).

Isn't it true that $$\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
p\leq x,q\leq x\\
pq>x
\end{array}}\frac{1}{pq}.$$ $$ =$$ $$\sum_{p \le x}\sum_{ x/p<q\le x} \frac{1}{pq}  $$ where the sums are over primes $p,q$?It has partially to do with Dirichlet's hyperbola method. So why in the first post the sum is $\pi^2/6 +Ο(1/\log x)$ while in the second it is  $O(\log\log x)$? Is it that it is just a loose approximation in the second one just to solve the exercise or I am missing something? Please help.

Comment: i'm not sure if i've understood.  your sums are equal, yes.  but the two questions concern different sums.  the condition $pq>x$ restricts the sum a lot (makes it smaller)

Comment: The problem is that the 2 sums seem equal to me but in the first question the sum is π^2/6+O(1/lnx) while the second question evaluates the sum as O(lnlnx)

Comment: This seems to confuse me. Why the asymptotic formulas are different? I get it that if something is π^2/6+O(1/lnx), then it is O(lnlnx). But is it true that the sums are equal and both asymptotic behaviors hold(like we show in every exercise what we need to prove) ? Or the sums are not equal?

Comment: Also the 2 questions are different but they use in their solutions these sums

Comment: i still don't get it sorry xD the sum $\sum _{pq<x}$ is of size $\approx \log \log x$.  the sum $\sum _{p,q<x;pq>x}$ is a different sum and it is smaller.  maybe write me precisely once more which sums you're confused about

Comment: I am confused about the sums that I wrote in the initial question. Are they equal?  The first post asks to compute the first of the sums that I wrote. The second post asks to compute another sum, but uses the second of the sums that I wrote to compute it.

Comment: yes, your sums in "isn't it true" are equal.  yep, the answer in the second post gives $O(log log p)$ but $O(1)$ is true.

Comment: So you are saying that the are equal, but it is just a loose approximation, just to solve the exersise?

Comment: the sums in your sentence "isn't it true that...." are equal, yes.

Comment: you mean the initial question right?

Comment: @tomos please answer to make it certain, you mean that the 2 sums in my initial questions are equal, right?

Comment: i don't know which ones you mean, but i think my last comment should be clear

Comment: i mean the 2 sums in the post i made ,the INITIAL question. not in the comments,

Comment: @tomos please make it clearer, do you mean that the 2 sums in my initial post-question that are equal? and it is just a somewhat loose approximation in the exercises to just solve them?

Comment: in your original psot you have a sentence that says "isn't it true that sum1=sum2".  that's true.

Answer (score 1):

There are two unrelated questions in the OP.

First, you ask if
$$\sum_{\substack{p\leq x,q\leq x\\pq>x}}\frac{1}{pq}
=
\sum_{p \le x}\sum_{ x/p<q\le x} \frac{1}{pq}. \tag{1}$$
This is true.

Implicitly, you seem to be suggesting that these are related to the sums in the
two linked questions are related. The sums in the two questions are

$$ \sum_{\substack{p \leq x, q \leq x \\ pq > x}} \frac{1}{pq} \tag{2} $$

and

$$ \sum_{pq \leq x} \frac{1}{pq} \tag{3}. $$

Sum $(1)$ is the same as sum $(2)$, but not the same as sum $(3)$. For example,
when $x = 10$, sum $(3)$ includes the summand $\frac{1}{2 \cdot 2} = \frac{1}{4}$, but sum
$(2)$ does not. More generally, sum $(3)$ includes the "large" summands coming from products of small primes, while $(2)$ omits these primes.